# Jet Pack: Navigation how to be notified when presented activity was dismissed?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I have a Parking view fragment with a button "book a place". If I have a user email and password then I have to open a navigator with a booking page but if the user has not filled his credentials I have to present a User Profile Fragment. After filling his profile and closing the view with "save" button the Parking View have to present a navigator with the booking page.

My question is: Using Navigation component, how it is possible to be notified that presented view fragment was closed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could go back from User Profile fragment to the Parking fragment with:

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

Then you could check if the user data is filled in onResume() method of Parking fragment. For example:

```
fun onResume(){
   if(userDataProvider.isDataFilled()) {
       navigateToBookingPage()
   } else {
       navigateToUserProfile()
   }
}
```